# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token?

Tags: c++, matlab, dllexport

I'm trying to compile a cpp file using mex (changeanalysis.cpp). I have Matlab R2012a, Xcode 4.6 on a MAC OS X 10.7. In the file changeanalysis.cpp, aef_global_dllexport.h is included. Some part of aef_global_dllexport.h is as follows:

```
    ////////////////////////
    // DLL EXPORT FUNCTIONS
    ////////////////////////
    #define DLLEXPORT _declspec(dllexport)


    DLLEXPORT double maha_dist_3D_ex(   double          x,
                                        double          y,
                                        double          z,
                                        double*         mean,
                                        double**        icovm);

    DLLEXPORT int matrix_inv_ND_ex(     double**        matND,
                                        double&         det,
                                        int             Dim);

    DLLEXPORT int matrix_copy3x3_ex(    double**        x, 
                                        double**        y);
    .
    .
    .
```

When I compile the file changeanalysis.cpp, I get  the following error message at the command prompt:

> mex -I"/Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB" changeanalysis.cpp
>
> In file included from changeanalysis.cpp:58:
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:7: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:13: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:17: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:20: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:22: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:24: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:29: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:31: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:50: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:75: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>   /Users/marzi/Documents/MATLAB/aef_global_dllexport.h:100: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>
> mex: compile of ' "changeanalysis.cpp"' failed.
>
> Error using mex (line 206) Unable to complete successfully.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what is the cause of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: The file `changeanalysis.cpp` is your file? Do any header files you include miss a semicolon at the end of a `struct` or `class`? Or miss a closing parenthesis or curly-brace?

Comment: This file is a part of a lung nodule segmentation project. As a new member to this project, I have to compile the files in order to generate Matlab mex plugin for segmenting lung nodules. In the file changeanalysis.cpp just the header file aef_global_dllexport.h is included.

Comment: The errors are at those lines of the header file (aef_global_dllexport.h) where there is a DLLEXPORT as the output of the function. Is this related to the fact that I'm working on a mac and I don't have a Visual Studio?

Comment: Isn't `_declspec` a VC++ only thing?

Comment: I think. So, what should I do now? Should I work on windows to compile these files?

Comment: On non-Windows platform `DLLEXPORT` is not needed. Use a preprocessor condition to have it defined as an empty macro in other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Windows notation to declare the exported functions. The notation you use should depend on the platform. You can be cross-platform compatible if you do this:

```
#if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__ || defined __MINGW32__
    #ifdef BUILDING_DLL
        #ifdef __GNUC__
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((dllexport))
        #else
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllexport) // Note: actually gcc seems to also supports this syntax.
        #endif
    #else
        #ifdef __GNUC__
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((dllimport))
        #else
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllimport) // Note: actually gcc seems to also supports this syntax.
        #endif
    #endif
    #define DLL_LOCAL
#else
    #if __GNUC__ >= 4
        #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
        #define DLL_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
    #else
        #define DLL_PUBLIC
        #define DLL_LOCAL
    #endif
#endif
```